# How to change img src attribute to data-src in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using this code to change the `src` attribute of an `img` element to `data-src`, but my current solution doesn't work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script>    
  $("img").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("data-src",$(this).attr("src"));
    $(this).removeAttr("src");
  }); 
</script>

<img src="test.jpg" width="300" height="200">
```

I want this output:

```
<img data-src="test.jpg" width="300" height="200">
```

Comment: This code should work fine. Are you sure the `data-src` attr is not appearing in the DOM? Inspect the element.

Comment: You'd better describe the expected result. Description looks strange for now

Comment: Is the Javcascript code inside `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: That code works just fine.  In js fiddle anyways...something else is the problem here.  Are you infact including Jquery?? And is 
 it inside $(document).ready() ?  https://jsfiddle.net/Lfst5evp/

Comment: @KyleK jsFiddle has its own login of placing JS and HTML. Looks like issue is really in "document ready".

Comment: @kumar-soni Are you sure that you need what you do? If you're trying to change normal img loading to lazy-loading, this might not work (if this html code is already in DOM) as images will start loading before you change img's src attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code:

```js
$("img").each(function() {
    
        $(this).attr("data-src",$(this).attr("src"));
        $(this).removeAttr("src");
        console.log($(this)[0].outerHTML);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

 
     </script>
        <img src="test.jpg" width="300" height="200">
```

Comment: This will add a property to the jQuery object, not an attribute accessible in the DOM.

Comment: <img data-src="test.jpg" width="300" height="200"> I want this output

Comment: @kumarsoni,  this solution is work for you?

Comment: No it does not I want this output <img data-src="test.jpg" width="300" height="200">

Comment: @kumarsoni , check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute your JS code after you add image in HTML, like this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="test.jpg" width="300" height="200">
<script>

$("img").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var src = $this.attr("src");
  $this.attr( "data-src", src );
  $this.removeAttr("src");
}); 

</script>
```